# Examples of inductivist theories of ethics?

Tags: reference-request, john-stuart-mill

In the "General Remarks" introduction to Mill's Utilitarianism, he distinguishes between "intuitive" and "inductive" schools of ethics.  By "intuitive" I take that he refers to what Russell calls the "system builders" who create theories founded on a priori principles.  Kant would be an example.

I'm not super sure precisely whom he is referring to by "inductive" schools of ethics.  Could someone provide examples of philosophers / ethical theories that would fall into this category? (Both as intended by Mill, and possibly those proceeding him)

Comment: I can find no examples of other philosophers taking this approach. (The more popular term "empirical ethics", which you might expect is synonymous, is not.) I've left an answer concerning Mill but, if there have been other inductivist approaches to ethics, I hope someone else explains at least one.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of any such theory, we take it as read some general laws are known empirically, various famous problems of induction notwithstanding. Mill, in particular, saw induction as a major source of knowledge, so it's unsurprising he'd seek to ground ethics in it rather than *a priori* reasoning. How does he try to do that? I'll summarise [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mill/#FounPracReasProo) account; see also Sec. 10 [here](https://iep.utm.edu/mill-eth).

A central challenge in acquiring ethical knowledge is that showing something is desired does not imply it's desirable, at least not in the sense deduction completes such an inference. Mill argues we know each person desires their own happiness. Consider one person: if their happiness is *desired* (by them), what tells us it's also *desirable*? Given Mill's empiricism, it's unsurprising he offers this analogy:

> The only proof capable of being given that an object is visible, is that people actually see it... the sole evidence it is possible to produce that anything is desirable, is that people do actually desire it.

(We could apply the same logic to desiring things other than happiness, but Mill contends these are desired because of the happiness they bring. I don't know whether other inductive ethicists have been less reductive.) In particular, desirability is not *defined* by what is desired; that would be an *a priori* case for it. Instead, we can only infer what is desirable for humans empirically, by seeing what they desire. He adds:

> each person’s happiness is a good to that person, and the general happiness, therefore, a good to the aggregate of all persons.

Critics argued Mill was saying each person tries to promote the happiness of all. He clarified:

> I merely meant in this particular sentence to argue that since A’s happiness is a good, B’s a good, C’s a good, &c., the sum of all these goods must be a good.

So in summary, Mill takes the universality of desiring happiness as inductive evidence it's desirable, takes individuals' desiring their own happiness as evidence these are each desirable, and takes their being respectively desirable as evidence they are also desirable in the aggregate.